# Mapping Custom Domains to Wildcard Sub-domains

Tags: next.js, wildcard, wildcard-subdomain

I'm creating a NextJS project which makes use of wildcard subdomains.

I've set up wildcard subdomains on Vercel, so now each wildcard subdomain points to my main NextJS installation. Within the NextJS app, I'm reading the subdomain name and serving the content accordingly.

So, let's say my wildcard entry is `*.example.com`

Now, all subdomains, such as `roman.example.com`, `greek.example.com`, are being served correctly with content coming from my database correctly.

The challenge I'm facing is to map custom domains to each of these subdomains.

For example, if I want `myroman.com` to map to `roman.example.com` and `mygreek.com` to map to `greek.example.com`, I'm unable to get it to work.

Say, for example, if in `myroman.com` DNS records, if I add a CNAME record pointing to `roman.example.com`, and then if I visit `myroman.com`, it shows me 404 deployments not found error. Note that something like `myroman.com` is a customer's site, and the only thing I can ask a customer is to add a DNS record to map it to a sub-domain. I cannot take control of their domain or anything like that.

You would see that companies like substack offer such custom domain mapping to their customers.

Can you suggest what's the best way to achieve this? I'm okay to change host or anything to make this work.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I need exactly the same thing. I would appreciate any direction you can suggest.

Comment: https://vercel.com/guides/nextjs-multi-tenant-application

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks to Krabs, we can host multiple websites inside of our Next.js instance and serve them separately depending on the domain that the user is browsing

https://micheleriva.github.io/krabs/docs/intro/

I hope this is what you are looking for!